# `aligned_alloc` in Linux Kernel Space when using kmalloc

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, heap-memory, kmalloc

I am writing a kernel module, porting some functionality from user space that uses the `aligned_alloc` function from the `#include <stdlib.h>` library. I did not find a similar function in the function accessible from kernel modules - is there any existing functionality or easy wrapper function I could write around `kmalloc` to replicate the behavior of `aligned_alloc`?

Comment: https://lwn.net/Articles/802469/

Comment: If you expect to be doing a lot of those (and of the same size), you can probably create a cache with `kmem_cache_create`, allocate from it with `kmem_cache_alloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent kernels (>= v5.4) `kmalloc()` is guaranteed to return naturally aligned objects of sizes that are powers of two, meaning that `kmalloc(sz)` is already aligned to `sz` IFF `sz` is a power of two. So if you are targeting modern kernels `kmalloc` is already enough. [Relevant patch here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=59bb47985c1db229ccff8c5deebecd54fc77d2a9).

If you need to support older kernels, or in general if you need a lot of allocations of the same kind, you can create your own `kmem_cache` with the appropriate object size and object alignment using [`kmem_cache_create()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.2/source/mm/slab_common.c#L361). You will then be able to allocate objects from it using [`kmem_cache_alloc()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.2/source/include/linux/slab.h#L290). Both are from `linux/slab.h`. Note however that this is only feasible if all the allocations you are dealing with are of the same size and need the same alignment.